# how build a wordpress query_posts based on url

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I want to use the query_posts function from wordpress for displaying the right posts. I want to use the url www.site.com/?s=taxonomy1=test1&taxonomy2=test2 for building the query. something like down here:

```
        $taxonomy1 = $_GET['taxonomy1'];
        $taxonomy2 = $_GET['taxonomy2'];

        query_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'taxonomy1' => $taxonomy1,
            'taxonomy2' => $taxonomy2,
        ) );>
```

How i do this?

Comment: [You really should use WP_Query in most cases.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: As @Howdy_McGee pointed out, `WP_Query` most of the times, `pre_get_posts` the other times, `query_posts`, NEVER EVER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is your best friend when trying to build custom queries.  something like this should work as a query

```
$taxonomy1 = $_GET['taxonomy1'];
$taxonomy2 = $_GET['taxonomy2'];

$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'tax_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
       'taxonomy' => $taxonomy1,
       'field' => 'slug',
     ),
     array(
       'taxonomy' => $taxonomy2,
       'field' => 'slug',
     ),
   ),  
));
```

and to display the results

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
  //the_title(), the_content(), etc
endwhile;
```

note that the query is using the new (as of 3.1) method for querying taxonomies.  As you can see it gives you a lot more flexibility and i would suggest reading through the above link

Comment: Although the OP said `query_posts`, you should NEVER EVER use `query_posts`. Use `WP_Query` or `pre_get_posts`

Comment: this function gives back an error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0